# convert a lisp string to a tree in c - program crushes but runs in debug mode

Tags: c, debugging, memory

I'm writing a program in `C` that is suppose to parse a string representing a tree into an actual tree in `C`.

The string format is Lisp style : 
for example the following string "(A(B)(C)(D))" will create a tree with A as root and B C D as 3 childs,

This is my Tree code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "SP_Tree.h"

typedef struct SP_NODE {
    char* value;
    int numchilds;
    struct SP_NODE* parent;
    struct SP_NODE** childs;
} SP_NODE;

SP_NODE* SPTreeCreate(char* value){
    SP_NODE *tree = (SP_NODE*)malloc(sizeof(SP_NODE));
    SP_NODE **childs = (SP_NODE**)malloc(sizeof(SP_NODE)*10);

    // initialize node data
    tree->childs = childs;
    tree->value = value;
    tree->parent = NULL;
    tree->numchilds = 0;
    return tree;
}
SP_NODE* SPInsertChild(SP_NODE* parent, SP_NODE* child, int index){
    // add node to parent in index place
    if (parent != NULL){
        parent->childs[index] = child;
        parent->numchilds++;
        child->parent = parent;
    }
    return child;
}
void SPDestroyTree(SP_NODE* root){
    if (root) {
        for (int i = 0; i < root->numchilds; i++){
            if (root->childs[i]!= NULL){
                SPDestroyTree(root->childs[i]);
            }
        }
        free(root->value);
        free(root);
    }
}
```

and here is my parser code:

```
SP_NODE* SPCreateLispTree(char* lisp){
    // create tree from first node
    int root_index = SPFindRoot(lisp);
    char* root_str = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*(root_index));
    strncpy(root_str, lisp+1, root_index -1);
    root_str[root_index-1] = '\0';
    SP_NODE* root = SPTreeCreate(root_str);

    // stop condition - current root ending with )
    if (lisp[root_index] == ')' ){
        return root;
    }

    // loop over all subtrees, add child to tree from each subtree
    int i = 0;
    int start_index = root_index;
    int next_index = SPFindNextSubtree(lisp,start_index);
    while (next_index > 0){
        // create tree from next subtree in lisp
        char* new_lisp = (char*)malloc(next_index-start_index+1);
        strncpy(new_lisp, lisp+start_index, next_index-2);
        new_lisp[next_index-start_index] = '\0';

        SP_NODE* next_child = SPCreateLispTree(new_lisp);

        // insert this new child to root
        SPInsertChild(root,next_child,i);

        // look for next subtree
        start_index = next_index;
        next_index = SPFindNextSubtree(lisp,start_index);
        i++;
    }
    return root;
}
int SPFindNextSubtree(char* lisp,int start_index){
    // run over string until we get #left_Parentheses == #right_Parentheses
    int i = start_index + 1;
    int left = 1;
    int right = 0;
    while (lisp[i] != '\0' && left != right){
        if (lisp[i] == '('){
            left++;

        }else if (lisp[i] == ')'){
            right++;
        }
        i++;
    }
    // if we finished with uneven number of Parentheses, its the last subtree
    if (left != right){
        fflush(stdout);
        return -1;
    }
    return i;
}
int SPFindRoot(char* lisp){
    // root will be from ( until first between ( or )
    // get index of first )
    char* right = strchr(lisp,')');
    int right_index = right - lisp;

    // get index of second '(' (first char will always be '(')
    char* left = strchr(lisp+1,'(');
    int left_index = left - lisp;

    // chose smaller index
    int index = right_index;
    if (left != NULL && left_index < right_index){
        index = left_index;
    }
    return index;
}
```

the code runs recursively over the string, finds the current root and creates a node from that root, then find every subtree after that root and creates a subtree from that.

my problem is - the program runs fine for small inputs -
but for bigger inputs, for example:

```
char* lisp = "(+(2)(*(5)(3(2)(3))(4(!)(2))(1))(2(3)(4)))";
SP_NODE* tree = SPCreateLispTree(lisp);
```

My program crushes.

BUT - it doesn't crush when I run in debug mode - and it produces the desired output.

Not sure what I'm doing wrong and how do I debug it.

Comment: Just for diagnostic purposes, in `SPTreeCreate()` try changing `SP_NODE **childs = (SP_NODE**)malloc(sizeof(SP_NODE)*10);` to `SP_NODE **childs = (SP_NODE**)malloc(sizeof(SP_NODE)*50);` and see if it still crashes.

Comment: yes, still crashes, also with bigger numbers - anyway I dont reach more then 10 child nodes in my program

Comment: yes youre right it should be  
sizeof(SP_NODE*)  , I changed it, but still crashing

Comment: `childs[index]` isn't initialized to `NULL`.

Comment: `strncpy(new_lisp, lisp+start_index, next_index-2);` --> `strncpy(new_lisp, lisp+start_index, next_index-start_index);`

Comment: thx! looks like it works fine now, I'm intrested why did the program crushed, but run fine in debug mode?

Comment: Added area for debugging mode may become the buffer zone of destruction which is not the intention of the memory.

Answer (score 0):

`childs[index]` isn't initialized to `NULL`.
                    – BLUEPIXY

`strncpy(new_lisp, lisp+start_index, next_index-2);` -->
`strncpy(new_lisp, lisp+start_index, next_index-start_index);`
                    – BLUEPIXY